# Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].select is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using SweetAlert to show an alert after I copy some text info.  I loop through the following code 5 times (because I have 5 different entries of text), increasing $num by 1 each time.

```
       <button  class="js-textareacopybtn copy-btn btn-info" data-id="<?php echo $num  ?>">COPY</button>
```

Here is the script

```
 <script>
    $('.js-textareacopybtn').on('click', function(event) {
    var copyTextarea = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + copyTextarea)[0].select();
    var msg=$('#' + copyTextarea)[0].value;
    try {
      var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
         Swal.fire({
         title: 'Copied!',
         text: 'Ready to paste and send',
         icon: 'success',
         showConfirmButton: false,
         timer: 1800
      })

      } catch (err) {
        alert('Unable to copy');
      }
    });

  </script>
```

This runs perfectly fine for the first 4 loops...the $num is correct and so is copyTextarea.  I can

But on the 5th run I get this error (even though $num is correct (it equals 5) and I validate that coptyTextarea is correct (also equals 5))

```
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].select is not a function
```

So the error occurs for the line

```
   $('#' + copyTextarea)[0].select();
```

I have no idea what could be going wrong

Comment: What is the result of `$(...)[0]`? And do you have a textarea with `id="5"`?

Comment: the result of that line is undefined whether its id=1,2,3,4,5   there is definitely text for id=5

Comment: Have you tried not using a numerical ID for the select? As IDs must start with a letter. Also, **.select()** is for the select event not the select element. I would try something like:  **var msg=$('#' + copyTextarea).val();**

Comment: Please add the output of your php (the html) to the question.

Comment: tried using .val and also a letter before the id number - same problem

Comment: Here is an example of the output for id=5 <input class="url_input" value="https://www.example.com" data-bs-container="body" html="true" data-bs-toggle="popover" id='5' data-bs-trigger="hover" title="Survey Page Link to Send" data-bs-content="https://www.example.com" data-bs-custom-class="beautifier">

Answer (score 0):

ok...the problem was that there was another id with the same value for just that one id..oh well, would never have found it since it was a quirk.